# Find the sum of the infinite series $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1\cdot3}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}+...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the sum of the series $\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1\cdot3}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}+...$.
This type of questions generally require a trick or something and i am not able to figure that out. My guess is that it has something to do with exponential series or binomial series. Any help?

Comment: Is $1.2.3.4$ supposed to mean $1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4$, etc.?

Comment: It's the product of these numbers

Comment: Did you try cancelling numerators with denominators? Maybe there's some good reason to have $1,3,5$ in both the numerator and denominator of the third term, but I can't see it.

Comment: Also: do you know about Taylor series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry guys, got it.
$\frac{1}{1\cdot 2}+\frac{1\cdot3}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4}+\frac{1\cdot3\cdot5}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6}+...=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2^2}\cdot\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{2^3}\cdot\frac{1}{3!}+... = e^\frac{1}{2}-1.$
The first equality holds after cancelling the common terms in the numerator and denominator